# Easy way to view doxygen commented file?

Tags: doxygen

I have one source file which describes interface of a class with many doxygen comments.

Maybe with doxygen it can be generated to a html that can be easily read and with handly cross-references, but I don't want to install a huge doxygen to my system just for viewing this file (in my Ubuntu it seems doxygen requires ~1GB disk space!).

Is there any quick/simple way to view doxygen commented file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to try the Linux binaries (or sources) from the official doxygen site (http://www.doxygen.org/download.html#srcbin). Then you are done with only 11.1MB of download (and maybe 50MB of disk space).

Ubuntu seems to make doxygen depend on all possible packages (including LaTeX) but these are mostly optional, and not needed for HTML output...

Answer (score 0):

If your using the Emacs text editor, you can install the [highlight-doxygen](https://github.com/Lindydancer/highlight-doxygen) package, it will highlight doxygen comments to that they will become much easier to read.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the doxygen within the package, you still don't get something you can look at.

The answer to the question I had when I got here was to run

```
doxygen -g
```

and then

```
doxygen
```

to produce html files in the html directory. The first produces the configName (default) and the second produces the html using the (default) cofiguration file.